# Is it possible to create scatch orgs that are a (metadata) copy of the developer hub org?

Tags: sandbox, salesforcedx, scratch-org

Is it possible to automatically create a scratch org with the same metadata as the developer hub org (like a sandbox) or do scratch orgs always start as a blank slate that's filled based on the configuration file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, scratch orgs are always "empty" when created. They're meant to be populated with metadata from your source code repository, which is the purpose of Salesforce DX. It's not "org-based development", the way that production/sandboxes are, but instead "source code-based development", where all of your configuration is in source control, and that code is the source of truth.

Comment: I will add to sfdcfox's answer and mention that the Hub Org is intended to be agnostic of the metadata in the scratch orgs... this is particularly important when handling managed packages and for the new packaging model that is coming soon.

Comment: So, then, I am failing to see the point of developing in scratch orgs. I can create entirely new objects and metadata. Great. I have been able to do that. But what about when I want to use metadata that is already in my production (or sandbox) org? Do I have to recreate the entire metadata?? This feels like a major failing. I'm currently struggling with getting the metadata from my sandbox to even be ABLE to be pushed to the scratch org. What is the point of this if I can't connect it to my actual org in a meaningful way?

Comment: @Chance Since this answer has been posted, there is a new feature: [org shape](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sfdx_pilot_shape.htm). This allows you to recreate your production's metadata using a simple command-line interface. Unfortunately, this is still in pilot, which means you need to sign up for it. It'll probably be developer preview in a release or so (hopefully, but usual "forward-looking statement" clause applies).

Comment: @Chance The point of a Dev Hub, though, is a place to organize and view all of your scratch orgs in one place, just as you'd do with if you wanted to see a list of all your sandboxes. The original intent was not to have it be a direct clone, but to be able to start from scratch, and deploy only fragments of your code base instead of every single field, object, code unit, etc. This means that a developer could set up their own unique environment in mere minutes instead of waiting hours for a sandbox copy.

Comment: @Chance And finally (apologize for all the comment notifications), most organizations have enough of a code base that doing it all in one run is impractical. You need to break this down into reasonable chunks as much as practical. Moving to DX from an existing project isn't an overnight change, it can easily take days or even weeks to fully sift through everything and get set up. New projects that start out with DX don't have to worry about that problem, of course.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks as always for the advice. I guess I am just struggling with DX. From an admin's perspective, I had a lot of hope for this tool because I thought it would help me develop. But it just seems that it is not the tool for the "admin-eloper" because I keep running into issues like this. I'm developing a pretty simple org, and it seems like you are saying the best step is for me to just develop in a sandbox rather than use DX and scrach orgs. Thanks again.